# Python asyncio: Can‘t debug into Task class

Tags: python, python-asyncio

When working with Python's `asyncio` package, I've noticed that I can't step into any code of its `tasks.Task` class. For example, when the calling code invokes the class's constructor, my next 'step into' get's me into a `get_debug()` function outside the class. After that, I return to the calling code with an initialised `Task` object. I've observed similar behaviour with `Task.__next_step()`: I'll just step into code that gets called by this method.

All Python versions (3.9, 3.10), IDEs (PyCharm, Visual Studio Code) and OSs (macOS, Windows) that I tested showed the same issue.

Does anyone know the reason for the debugger’s strange behaviour and, possibly, how to overcome it?

[image: Illustration of the behaviour within pdb (Python 3.8)]

The `call_soon()` in the last line of the screenshot is issued from within `Task.__init__`. However, as you can see, the debugger never stepped into the initializer.

Update: Surprisingly, with Python 3.6 (Pythonista on iPadOS) I can step into `Task.__init__` from `base_events.BaseEventLoop.create_task()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `Task` is in C (where available). The debugger cannot step into C code.

You can see this in the `asyncio.tasks` module:

```py
class Task(futures._PyFuture):
    ...


_PyTask = Task


try:
    import _asyncio
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    # _CTask is needed for tests.
    Task = _CTask = _asyncio.Task
```

That last line shows the Python implementation being overridden by the C implementation.

You can verify which implementation you have by inspecting the `__module__` attribute of `Task`. e.g.

```py
import asyncio
print(asyncio.Task.__module__)
```

A pure Python implementation will print `asyncio.tasks`. The C implementation will print `_asyncio`.